# Render jQuery object through Backbone View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, hogan.js

I'm rather new to Backbone.js development, and have run into a bit of a roadblock while attempting to render a subview.

Currently, I have in place several views to render a custom dropdown-button, as well as other elements.  I've taken this approach based on [DocumentCloud's code](https://github.com/documentcloud/documentcloud/blob/master/public/javascripts/ui/common/menu.js)

Here's what I have so far:

```
app.ui.SelectMenu = Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'btn-group group-item',

    options: {
        id: null,
        standalone: false
    },

    events: {
        "click .dropdown-menu a": "setLabel"
    },

    constructor: function (options) {
        Backbone.View.call(this, options);

        this.items = [];
        this.content = JST['common-select_button'];
        this.itemsContainer = $('.dropdown-menu', $(this.content.render()));

        // Add any items that we may have added to the object params
        if (options.items) {
            this.addItems(options.items);
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.content.render({
            label: this.options.label,
            items: this.itemsContainer
        }));
        this._label = this.$('.menu-label');
        return this;
    },

    setLabel: function (label) {
        $(this._label).text(label || this.options.label);
    },

    addItems: function (items) {
        this.items = this.items.concat(items);
        var elements = _(items).map(_.bind(function (item) {
            var attrs = item.attrs || {};
            _.extend(attrs, { 'class': 'menu_item' + (attrs['class'] || '') });

            var el = this.make('li', attrs, item.title);
            return el;
        }, this));

        $(this.itemsContainer).append(elements);
    }
});
```

So far I have successfully rendered my button, as well as the appropriate label, but I cannot seem to populate the `.dropdown-menu` when calling the `addItems` function.

I'm assuming that when `render` hits, the items variable cannot be populated due to the fact that I am passing a jQuery object and not a string, yet whenever I use `items: this.itemsContainer.html()`, that simply pastes the html surrounded by quotes...  I could simply replace the quotes but that just feels like a hack to me.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) doesn't take an array:

> **`.append( content [, content] )`**
>
> **content**: DOM element, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements.
>   **content**: One or more additional DOM elements, arrays of elements, HTML strings, or jQuery objects to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

If you want to append multiple elements in one call, you have to supply them as separate arguments:

```
$(x).append(e1, e2, e3, ...);
```

so you'd have to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to convert your array to separate arguments:

```
var $i = $(this.itemsContainer);
$i.append.apply($i, elements);
```

That sort of chicanery really isn't necessary though, you can add them one by one as you create them:

```
addItems: function (items) {
    this.items = this.items.concat(items);
    _(items).each(function (item) {
        var attrs = item.attrs || {};
        _.extend(attrs, { 'class': 'menu_item' + (attrs['class'] || '') });

        this.itemsContainer.append(this.make('li', attrs, item.title));
    }, this);
}
```

Also note that [`_.each`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each) can take a `context` argument so you don't need a separate [`_.bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind) call. And I'm pretty sure that `this.itemsContainer` is already a jQuery object so you don't need to wrap it `$()` again.

You might have problems with your `render` as well:

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.content.render({
        label: this.options.label,
        items: this.itemsContainer
    }));
    this._label = this.$('.menu-label');
    return this;
}
```

I suspect that `items: this.itemsContainer` is going to end stringifying `this.itemsContainer`, you might have better luck with something like this:

```
this.$el.html(this.content.render({ label: this.options.label });
this.$el.find('some selector').append(this.itemsContainer);
```

where `'some selector'` would, of course, depend on the HTML structure; you'll have to adjust the template for this as well.

---

Your Github link is broken so I don't know what code you're adapting. I do know that your use of `constructor` is non-standard. Why not use the standard [`initialize`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor)?

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>
> [...]  If the view defines an `initialize` function, it will be called when the view is first created.

You should probably do it this way:

```
app.ui.SelectMenu = Backbone.View.extend({
    // No 'constructor' in here or anywhere...
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.items = [];
        this.content = JST['common-select_button'];
        this.itemsContainer = $('.dropdown-menu', $(this.content.render()));

        // Add any items that we may have added to the object params
        if (options.items) {
            this.addItems(options.items);
        }
    },
    //...
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great answer!  Very informative and helpful.

I've edited the Github link to properly reflect what source I am working off of.  I assumed that since this is something that [jashkanes](https://twitter.com/#!/jashkenas) works on, then the use of `constructor` would be good to go.  Thanks again for the detailed response, mate.

Comment: @Jaysche: I don't get the use of `constructor` in there, perhaps it is just old code that predates `initialize` in Backbone. The use of `$(this.el)` rather than `this.$el` does suggest that it is a bit older and may not have been updated for for newer Backbones.

Comment: I suppose that would make sense. I was doing some reading about DocumentCloud and apparently Backbone was created through extracted portions of code from said project, so that's most likely what is going on here. Thanks again!